# How can I read from a file and alphabetically order the contents of that file into a Linked List?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make a LinkedList class that is able to add as data file from a content. I get thrown a NullPointerException and I am not entirely sure why. Is there a better way to go about this problem without using Collections.sort?

```
public class LinkedList {

    // Properties
    Node head;
    int count;

    // Constructors
    public LinkedList() {
        head = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    public LinkedList(Node newHead) {
        head = newHead;
        count += 1;
    }

    // Methods
    // add
    public void add(String newData) {
        Node temp = new Node(newData);
        Node current = head;

        while (current.getNext() != null) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNext(temp);
        count++;
    }

//================================================================================================

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Access the contents of a file
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Marlene\\Workspace\\LinkedDict\\src\\com\\company\\unsorteddict.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

        String fileContents = "";
        LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();

        com.company.LinkedList linkedList = new com.company.LinkedList();
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            linkedList.add(fileContents);
        }

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(
                "C:\\Users\\Marlene\\Workspace\\LinkedDict\\src\\com\\company\\sorteddict.txt");
        writer.write(fileContents);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  In particular, include the full error message (traceback) and your trace of critical values up to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Fix noted in comment.

```
    public void add(String newData) {
        Node temp = new Node(newData);
        if(head == null){                    // fix
            head = temp;
            count = 1;
            return;
        }
        Node current = head;
        while (current.getNext() != null) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNext(temp);
        count++;
    }
```

---

For the sort, a bottom up merge sort for a linked list is reasonably fast. Wiki article includes pseudo code example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

Depending on how large the nodes are, it may be faster to create an array from the list, sort the array, then create a new sorted list from the sorted array.